# Why must new Java objects be created in the Eden space?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

Java Garbage Collection uses a copy collector for young objects. The Young Generation area is divided into “Eden Space” and two Survivor Spaces, s0 and s1.

I understand that the copy collector copies surviving objects from Eden and one Survivor space into the other survivor space.

Conceptually 2 spaces should be enough, copying survivors from one space into the other. I assume the reason Java uses 3 spaces rather than just 2 is so that new objects can always be created in the same place, in the Eden area.

The question is why is it important that new (young-space) objects be created in the Eden area, and not for example after the last copied object in the "copied-to" survivor space?

Comment: “after the last object of the survivor space” is a single location. Not helpful for a JVM where an arbitrary number of threads can make allocations. So usually, each thread fetches a TLAB from the Young Generation and the area from which they are taken, is called the Eden space. Whether that’s a real thing (with inflexible boundaries) or just a logical name, depends on the particular garbage collector.

Answer (score 2):

The alternative you are proposing has two equal-sized new spaces and copying from one to the other.  You will find that you need to run a new generation GC when half of the (total) new space is filled.

In the approach used by the Oracle GCs, where (typically) Eden size > S1 size + S2 size, you have filled all of Eden + part of S1 (or S2) by the time that you run a new generation GC.  That will be significantly more that half of the total new space memory.  In other words, new space memory is used more efficiently.

This Oracle training material has some nice diagrams that explain what happens during new and old generation GC:

- [Java Garbage Collection Basics](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html)

But note that the tutorial is describing a simplified generational collector.  The details vary significantly across the various *actual* collectors supported by different versions of Java.

Comment: Thanks. If Eden>S1+S2, isn't it risking not enough space being available in S2 to store Eden+s1 survivors? And If the mortality rate is high enough to avoid that, would an S3, S4 and so on increase space usage further?

Comment: If S1 isn't big enough to hold the survivors, objects will be tenured.

Answer (score 2):

In case of G1 there is only one survivor space (though for compatibility JVM reports existence of two spaces).

With G1 collector all heap is single pool and "functional" spaces are fully dynamic. Thus survivor space is allocated only for collection (and become a part of eden once collection is finished.

Most other collectors supported in HotSpot JVM require "functional" spaces to have static boundaries which are defined on JVM startup. Thus empty survivor space cannot become a part of eden.

Comment: But the G1 survivor space is split up into many separate regions, right?

Comment: @GonenI with G1 all heap is split into regions. Though region can be a part of survivor at one point and part of eden or event old space in another.